# Google cloud (GCP) SQL limit on the SSL certificates

Tags: mysql, ssl, google-cloud-platform, certificate

Our company uses MySQL on the GCP.
For the prod database, we use SSL certificates - we have one for our services and a couple of "personal" certs for different developers.
Currently, I'm creating new certificates for other developers and I just noticed that GCP allows only to create up to 10 (!) certificates per database - which is no way enough if we want to issue each developer its own personal certificate.
Is there any way to overcome this limitation? The goal is to have a separate SSL certificate per developer, which is a much higher number than 10.

Comment: Why to have 1 certificate per user? Which security case do you cover with this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to overdesign a solution. The SSL certificate is used to encrypt connections. This does not help you with identity/database security beyond encrypted connections. Use MySQL style security to protect database access in addition to SSL connection encryption. SSL setup is a CPU intensive action. Multiple certificates adds to that overhead. I recommend limiting your certificates to groups of users and not one per user.

> Is there any way to overcome this limitation?

No, this is a hard limit that you cannot change.

Consider using the Cloud SQL Proxy which provides multiple additional benefits.

[About the Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)